# angular http interceptor response header

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am making a post request (login).

it returns a token in the response header(Set-Auth).

How can extract and use the token in a request header?

[image: response header]

```
    login() {

    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      this.messageService.warning('You\'re missing something important', null);
      return;
    }

    this.connecting.creating = true;

    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      console.log(this.loginForm.value);
      this.adminService.submitLogin(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.messageService.success('Login Success', 'Success!');
          this.router.navigate(['']).then();
        },
        error => {
          this.messageService.error('Something went wrong', 'Error!');
          this.connecting.creating = false;
          this.connectingErrors.creating = true;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Read this: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 1):

You need to return token inside response body.
Get that value and store it inside localStorage. Then create interceptor like this..

```
// src/app/auth/token.interceptor.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

```
// src/app/app.module.ts
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './../auth/token.interceptor';
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

After this on every http request token will be attached on the header as Authorization...

It's dangerous to store jwt tokens in local storage so I suggest you secure cookie approach because of XSS attack.